# Linq query update all items in groups that meet my condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want to update the property "IsQualified= True" for-

1. All students in only qualified groups
2. Qualified groups? Those groups that have at least one student who passed from "University= OPQ" (Example: Group 2 and 3)
3. Leave other group students' "IsQualified" property unchanged. (Example: Group 1)

**What I tried-**

```
var results = studentsList
.Where(x => x.University= OPQ)
.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
.SelectMany(g => g)
.ToList();

results.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = true);
```

This doesn't work. Please help me.

My Code-

```
public class StudentInfo
{
  public string Student { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public bool IsQualified {get; set;}

}

List<StudentInfo> studentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="ABC", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False});
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="DEF", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="GHI", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False} );

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="JKL", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ABC", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emity", University="OPQ", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emma", University="GHI", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="DEF", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="GHI", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jacob", University="ABC", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Matthew", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Saint", University="VWX", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Joshua", University="TRP", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Aubrey", University="STU", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
```

Comment: _"This doesn't work"_ - is not helpfull. What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: It updates only matching students, and not all students in groups that meet Condition (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oOsi1G)

1. You need to get all qualified groups by grouping then where the condition
2. Loop all `StudentsList` list to update `IsQualified` accordingly.

   ```
   var qualifiedGroups = StudentsList
                .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
                .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.University == "OPQ"))
                .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

   StudentsList.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = Array.IndexOf(qualifiedGroups, x.GroupID) != -1);

   foreach(var item in StudentsList)
       Console.WriteLine("Group:" + item.GroupID + " Student:" + item.Student +  " IsQualified:" + item.IsQualified);
   ```

**Output**

```
Group:1 Student:John IsQualified:False
Group:1 Student:Jack IsQualified:False
Group:1 Student:Peter IsQualified:False
Group:2 Student:Donald IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Olivia IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Emity IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Emma IsQualified:True
Group:2 Student:Alan IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Adam IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Jacob IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Matthew IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Saint IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Joshua IsQualified:True
Group:3 Student:Aubrey IsQualified:True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filtering is wrong.

You need to group first, then filter second. Otherwise you are grouping by a very select list.

```
var results = studentsList
             .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
             .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.University == "OPQ"))
             .SelectMany(g => g)
             .ToList();

results.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your solution is applying **where** condition before grouping the results. It will filter out the other students who are in GroupId 2 and 3,

[image]

You have to group the results first and then apply the condition "*Those groups that have at least one student who passed from "University= OPQ"*"

```
var results = studentsList
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
            .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.University == "OPQ"))
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToList();
```

[image]

Then you can do the foreach to update the IsQualified field,

```
results.ForEach(x => x.IsQualified = true);
```